# How do I fix melds 'Cannot import: GTK+' error caused by missing 'gi.repository'?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, meld

I've recently started learning GTK+ development and installed some new packages (I don't remember which ones). Now the merge tool `meld` doesn't work any more:

```
Cannot import: GTK+
No module named repository
```

This is caused by line 155 of the meld executable:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

Note that I can import `gi.repository` in Python 3, but it is not so simple to convert meld to Python 3.

How can I fix it?

### What I've tried:

- `sudo apt-get install python-gobject`: Was already installed ([source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/typecatcher/+bug/1258885))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the [`gi`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gi) package installed:

```
$ sudo pip uninstall gi
```

fixed my problem.

Comment: Why does uninstalling gi help when gi.repositories is needed? I have the inverse problem, of meld missing gi, and not finding ``gi.repository`` when I do install it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401677.

Comment: The package `gi` is something about Github gists. It is not related to `gi.repository` / GTK

Comment: found it! gi.repository is part of python-gobject-cairo -- that was not obvious at all...

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this - but forgot that I was working inside a virtualenv that didn't have this stuff installed. Just needed to run the command from outside the virtualenv.