# Meld error "Cannot import: GTK+; No module named repository"

Tags: python, meld

Meld used to work on my machine (openSuse Linux 13.1, Python 2.7.6) but after having trouble with Spyder (like it refusing to actually run any scripts), I uninstalled a large number of things, then slowly brought them back again.

Since then, meld does not work anymore. I keep getting this error message

```
> meld
Cannot import: GTK+
No module named gi
```

I was able to solve that by installing gi:

```
> pip install gi
```

Now the error is replaced by:

```
> meld
Cannot import: GTK+
No module named repository
```

... and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657717) is a similar question where uninstalling `gi` apparently helped? I'm confused. I did try uninstalling it again but that just brought me back to the previous error (duh!).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, that was not obvious:

`gi.repository` is not part of `gi` but its own thing. That's why `gi` should not be installed (thank you [Moose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657717/how-do-i-fix-melds-cannot-import-gtk-error-caused-by-missing-gi-repository)).

[This article](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/python-importerror-no-module-named-gi-repository-921361/) then pointed me to a possible source, `python-gobject`. However, I already had that installed. So I installed other things that looked similar, and the `python-gobject-cairo` package ( Python 2.7, openSuse 13.1) did the trick. Seems like someone overlooked a dependency for Meld...

Comment: it says unable to locate package python-gobject-cairo. Please help

Comment: @sanket: Is that when you're running ``yum install python-gobject-cairo``? Are you also running openSuse 13.1?  I've since migrated to Leap 42, and it's in the main repository, so I'd assume that's where it should be on 13.1, too. Are you sure your repos are configured right?

Answer (score 2):

If your `python3` refers to python3.7 or higher version, and there is python3 below 3.7 in your system(or install one), such as python3.6(/usr/bin/python3.6), this may works:

```
sudo vi `which meld`
```

**and** change the `python3` to `python3.6` in line1, and save, reopen the meld.

Answer (score 1):

I unlinked the file that was showing in Expected in:

> Expected in: /Applications/Meld.app/Contents/Frameworks/libz.1.dylib

```
unlink /Applications/Meld.app/Contents/Frameworks/libz.1.dylib
```

Answer (score 1):

After changing python3 from version 3.7 to 3.6 error disappeared.

I have done that by:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me, thank you!